# Setting up account to start using Collector for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-online, mobile, data-collection, arcgis-collector

I'm working on a presentation topic around mobile-based data collection solutions. I've used ODK and Fulcrum in production and absolutely love them. However, I'm going to be presenting to an Esri crowd so I want to at least add Collector for ArcGIS to the pool of candidates for comparison.

How do you get this working?

It's difficult to "test"  this product out. I've had an Esri global account now for about 10 years.  I can't use that ArcGIS.com account in collector because it is not an "organizational account" (which I don't understand because it is the login tied to our corporate licenses). I created a new account using the "30-day Free Trial" found at http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline.

I created a new map, added an editable layer to the map, saved the map, shared the map publicly, and to a fake group I made, I even added a dummy email (user account) as a member of the group/organization, and yet when I go into Collector and login with either my admin email, or the dummy email, no maps show to be available.

I've been poking around online and within the Esri forums this morning for about 3 hours trying to troubleshoot the issue. My first thought was that I couldn't use Collector with a "trial" ArcGIS Online account, but most everything I read from Esri reps stated otherwise. Perhaps that has changed.

Does anyone have any insight to provide on this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I believe ESRI would be the best people to talk to about this. I've setup Collector a few different times and it's a really cool product, especially when using feature services directly from ArcGIS Server, but there are a lot of different factors that could be causing you problems. Without having your map or data it's impossible to tell you what you're doing wrong.

One thing you may be missing is that when you first start the app and login, you need to enter the URL of your organization, for example:

organization.maps.arcgis.com

And then enter your username/password that is associated with the organization. This username also needs to be set to either an Administrator or Publisher role.

---

This ESRI post seems to be exactly what you're asking:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/89386-Please-use-an-organizational-account-error-on-collector

> kylie from ESRI:
>
> There are two different accounts that you can get for no cost. One is
>   a public account. Public accounts are not supported in Collector. The
>   other is a 30-day free trial of an ArcGIS subscription. Those are
>   supported with Collector. You will need to set up your organization,
>   and then you will be able to log in with the account tied to that
>   30-day trial. By set up your organization, it is not paying for it.
>   When you create the free trial you will get email that explains what
>   you need to do.

---

What's all in your map?

Are you adding a shapefile? Did you make sure to check "Publish this file as a feature layer"? The editable layer has to be a feature service. Also, you need to turn editing on for the feature. I'll add some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

If editing says Disabled, you need to click Edit and at the bottom of the page turn it on.

Go into the map on AGO and make sure you can edit it there.

Comment: Thanks ian. I am logging into my org's AGO portal with the proper URL. Yes I have already reviewed all of the ESRI forum related to my topic. In fact my trial account with AGO was registered through the link in that post, yet I'm still unable to connect to "My Maps". You're right about contacting ESRI in regards to this. However, I have no production-level need to test this product so I'll just move on. From what I can tell Collector does not support a relational database (many-to-one) structure that I require for nearly all of our data collection. At least not w/out ArcGIS for Server.

Comment: I added a little more input, can you verify that you are indeed using the feature service layer and that editing is enabled? Because I just made a test map and it didn't show up until I made these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an older post, if anyone is interested ArcGIS online now supports 1:M relations and domains. See http://communityhub.esriuk.com/journal/2014/10/10/the-wonderful-world-of-tables-in-arcgis-online.html

It allows you to edit tables within your browser, use domains to allow for drop-down boxes within your data and have related tables.

I believe you must still have an organisational account though.