# Editing of layers on an ArcGIS server in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

We have an ArcGIS server with REST API, containing some feature layers we want to edit also on machines without ArcGIS Desktop, ideally through ArcGIS Collector. We don't have the Portal, but we have ArcGIS Online organization account. However, [this says that only hosted layers can be set edittable](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/edit-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C8E28601D97A4E9892BF3735367B533F), and maps without edittable layers seems to be invisible for ArcGIS Explorer. We can't afford keeping all the layers to be editted as hosted ones.

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91498/12768) mentioned working directly with the feature server's services, so it should be possible, even though I didn't find how to do it in a day of searching. So how to make the Collector work with the layers without hosting them to AGOL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AGOL web maps are not restricted to just hosted feature services inside your organization. You can use ArcGIS Server feature services but sometimes depending on your server network you may have a message displayed in the web map that editing is disabled due to the server coming from an internal network. This is only a limitation in web map in ArcGIS Online and Collector will still be able to edit these services. Also with the web map saying these layers are not editable you will be required to have an editable layer in the web map like a dummy hosted feature service that will give the web map the Collector flag which helps the app find maps that can be used in Collector.

Comment: We enabled few feature services and it works! We even don't need the dummy layer any more. Thanks!