# Seeing maps created by others in organization in ArcGIS Collector?

Tags: arcgis-online, mobile, arcgis-collector

A follow-up question for [Editing of layers on an ArcGIS server in ArcGIS Collector](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/165486/12768)

I know it's in [ArcGIS Collector's FAQ](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/android/create-maps/faqs-create-map.htm#anchor2), but we have met all the requirements specified there and still we can't see others maps within our organization. My co-worker's map is shared with everyone and I can edit it in ArcGIS Online even outside our organization's admin account. However, I can't see it among "all maps" in ArcGIS Collector. The editable layer on his map is shared from a feature service on our organization's server; I have the same layer on one of my maps as well. Saving the layer as a hosted one on that invisible map doesn't make it appear.

So, what may we be doing wrong and how to make all our organization's maps visible and editable by everyone at least in our organization?

Comment: when you published the map service did you check mobile data access and feature access?

Comment: @user3338197: yes. But even if it wasn't set, my other map with the same feature service layer as the only editable layer would be invisible as well - I intentionally made a map that differs from my co-worker's one only by owner, to test this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to enabled Feature Access on the service when publishing and have some variant of Add/Update/Delete enabled.

Also you need to share the map and layers to a group that your other org members are a part off. The app will only display maps shared across groups that you are a member of or maps that exist under your My Content. These maps also need to have an editable layer included to be picked up by the app when it accesses your available content.

Comment: Sorry for waiting so long before accepting your answer. I was assigned to an unrelated project. Now I returned to ArcGIS Collector, shared all layers within a group and it works!